# XQuery how to get whole xml document with WHERE query

Tags: xquery, berkeley-db-xml

I have XML db with only one collection (container) and I don't know the document names. How to get a entire XML document from db, which complies WHERE clause?

```
<root>
      <node1>
            <node2>
                   <node3>My Content</node2>
            </node2>
      </node1>
<root>
```

When I have queries

```
query 'collection("data1.dbxml")/root/node1/node2[node3 = "My Content"]/string()'
```

it returns a content from that node3

```
'My Content'
```

and

```
query 'collection("data1.dbxml")/root/ode1/node2/node3'
```

it returns 2 internal nodes with the content

```
<node2><node3>My Content</node3></node2>
```

But how to get whole document which complies this WHERE clause (sth like SELECT * FROM data2.dbxml WHERE node3='My Content'?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a predicate as you did in the first example:

```
  collection("data1.dbxml")/root[node1/node2/node3 = "My Content"]
```

You can think of the predicate in XQuery as the WHERE in SQL and the SELECT-part is everything before.

Answer (score 0):

another resolution ... after studying :)

```
query 'for $x in collection("data1.dbxml") 
       where $x/root/node1/node2/node3 = "My Content"
       return $x'
```

or when we know the depth of node in XMLdoc and node's name

```
query 'for $x in collection("data1.dbxml") 
       where $x/*/*/*/node3 = "My Content"
       return $x'
```

thanks [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_select.asp)

Comment: Don't quote or consult W3Schools, they are known to spread misinformation.